# mysql group by, max, count implementaion

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

tables

```
items table
------------------
| id |   item    |
------------------
| 1  |   pearl   |
| 2  |   ruby    |
| 3  |   gold    |
| 4  |   diamond |
------------------
```

```
transaction table
--------------------------------------------------
| item_id |   sell_price   |    created_at       |
--------------------------------------------------
|    1    |      10        | 2020-08-21 01:50:24 |
|    1    |      20        | 2020-08-22 05:51:10 |
|    3    |      20        | 2020-08-23 06:52:05 |
|    3    |      30        | 2020-08-24 22:55:07 |
|    4    |      50        | 2020-08-25 20:58:18 |
|    2    |      10        | 2020-08-26 12:59:55 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

expected output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| item_id |  name    |   quantity    | price |    created_at       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |  pearl   |      2        |  20   | 2020-08-22 05:51:10 |
|    2    |  ruby    |      1        |  10   | 2020-08-26 12:59:55 |
|    3    |  gold    |      2        |  30   | 2020-08-24 22:55:07 |
|    4    |  diamond |      1        |  50   | 2020-08-25 20:58:18 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the query

```
SELECT
    items.id AS item_id,
    items.item,
    COUNT(transaction.item_id) AS quantity,
    MAX(transaction.price) AS sell_price
FROM transaction
LEFT JOIN items
ON transaction.item_id = items.id 
GROUP BY transaction.item_id;
```

My query above works perfectly fine without `transaction.created_at` on `select` clause, but when I put `select transaction.created_at` it throws an error:

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.transaction.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Specify MySQL version. This is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the desired output you shared, it looks like you're trying to query the maximum `created_at`:

```sql
SELECT
    items.id AS item_id,
    items.item,
    COUNT(transaction.item_id) AS quantity,
    MAX(transaction.price) AS sell_price,
    MAX(created_at) AS created_at -- Here!
FROM transaction
LEFT JOIN items
ON transaction.item_id = items.id 
GROUP BY transaction.item_id;
```

Comment: Will give wrong output if the last price is lower than some intermediate one.

Answer (score 1):

When using `GROUP BY`, just list all columns that are in `SELECT` and that not inside an aggregate function.

```
SELECT
    items.id AS item_id,
    items.item,
    COUNT(transaction.item_id) AS quantity,
    MAX(transaction.sell_price) AS sell_price,
    MAX(transaction.created_at) AS created_at
FROM transaction
LEFT JOIN items
ON transaction.item_id = items.id 
GROUP BY items.id, items.item;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mx3bQxTbq9i7ckg3r76ZZd/0).